# Simplifying multiple identical tests in unittest

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing

I'm trying to figure out how to simplify and expand the following unit test.

```
import unittest
import MyPackage

class MyPackageUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.Instance = MyPackage.MyObject.Setup()  # Initial setup of our object

class TypeATest(MyPackageUnitTest):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TypeATest, cls).setUpClass()   # Run setup for an instance of the MyObject object

    def setUp(self):
        self.Instance.Run("inputFileA.txt")  # Run expensive code with inputFileA.txt

    def test_check_for_red(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance, "red"))  # After code is run, check for 'red' attribute

    def test_check_for_blue(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance, "blue"))  # After code is run, check for 'blue' attribute

    def test_check_for_uniqueA(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance, "uniqueA"))  # After code is run, check for things unique to inputFileA.txt's run path

class TypeBTest(MyPackageUnitTest):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TypeATest, cls).setUpClass()

    def setUp(self):
        self.Instance.Run("inputFileB.txt")  # Run expensive code with inputFileB.txt

    def test_check_for_red(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance, "red")) # After code is run, check for 'red' attribute
 
    def test_check_for_blue(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance, "blue"))  # After code is run, check for 'blue' attribute

    def test_check_for_uniqueB(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance, "uniqueB"))  # After code is run, check for things unique to inputFileB.txt's run path
```

The way this works is that an instance of `MyPackage.MyObject` is created, and a setup procedure is run to setup certain things. Then, `Run()` is run with an input file to run most of the code. Now, we want to run tests on multiple input files that run through different paths of our code to make sure each path works properly. However, regardless of the path, at the end of a run, an instance needs to have certain attributes (here, `Instance.red` and `Instance.blue`). Since this is going to be expanded to a few more paths, and there are common tests (i.e., looking for red and blue), I wanted to figure out how to re-use those tests.

My attempt was to do a

```
class CommonMethods(MyPackageUnitTest):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(CommonMethods, cls).setUpClass()

    def test_check_for_red(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance), "red")

    def test_check_for_blue(cls):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance), "blue")
```

and then do, as an example,

```
class TypeATest(CommonMethods):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(TypeATest, cls).setUpClass()

    def test_check_for_uniqueA(self):
        self.assertTrue(hasattr(self.Instance, "uniqueA"))
```

However, when I run `unittest.main()`, the `CommonMethods()` methods are executed, but those attributes don't exist until `Run()` is executed. How do I make it so that I can have these common methods that are only executed after, e.g., `TypeATest()` has run its `setUp()` without putting them in every single TypeATest, TypeBTest, TypeCTest...? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand - you don't want to put the `setUp` calls in these classes? You could put the `setUp` into your `CommonMethods` and take the filename from a methos that is implemented in each test class. Or maybe I'm not understanding the problem...

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Correct. I'm new to this so, so maybe I'm doing it wrong, but it sounds like setUp will run for every method in the test class. However, it's super expensive and should only be run once in `TypeXTest`. I need `.Run()` to be called once in `TypeATest`, followed by `test_check_for_red` and `test_check-for_blue`, and then it runs once for `TypeBTest`, followed by `test_check_for_red` and `test_check_for_blue`. But since there's going to be a `TypeCTest`, `TypeDTest`, etc. as well as more `test_check_for_green`, `test_check_for_brown`, I'd like to simplify.

Comment: If you want it run once in `TypeXTest`, it belongs in `setUpClass`, not in `setUp`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Ah! Yup, that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks!